# Tell if jQuery DOM element is draggable or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Does jQuery UI store any properties to a jQuery dom ref element?

What I'm particular interested in is any data or properties or function that can tell is
it draggable?

Example:

```
var jqnode = jQuery('selector');
jqnode.draggable({...});
var isDraggable = !!(jqnode.tellIsDraggableProperty);
```

Comment: Have you tried `jqnode.hasClass('ui-draggable')`?

Comment: No, I don't want to depend on something that is easily editable outside of the scope of my app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isDraggable = !!jqnode.data("draggable")
```

or

```
var isDraggable = jqnode.is(":ui-draggable");
```

Depending on what you want to do, you could use the selector in the original:

```
jQuery('selector:ui-draggable').fn()
```

This would neatly only call `fn` if it was draggable.

Comment: Could you show me where you found the `:ui-draggable` selector? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @Blender in the source code https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L41

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you ask if I understand correctly.

```
var jqnode = jQuery('selector');
var isDraggable = (typeof jqnode.draggable === 'function');
```

Also, I think hasOwnProperty() would work too:

```
var jqnode = jQuery('selector');
var isDraggable = jqnode.hasOwnProperty('draggable');
```

Answer (score 1):

When jQueryUI initializes the `draggable`, it add a `ui-draggable` class to the element:

```
var isDraggable = jqnode.hasClass('ui-draggable');
```

Comment: In that case, he could do `var isDraggable = jQuery('selector.ui-draggable');`

Comment: Yes, that's an obviuos solution but I'm not looking for something different :)

Comment: @crush - Nope. Even if jQuery doesn't find what your looking for in the DOM, it still returns a jQuery object.

Comment: @kidwon - Why in the world??

Comment: @JosephSilber Then you just check the length of the object it returns. `var isDraggable = jQuery('selector.ui-draggable').length > 0;`

Comment: @crush - So you're saying that creating a separate object is better than using the object already created?

Comment: @JosephSilber No that's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying there is no need to create the jqnode var unless he is using it elsewhere, which there is no evidence he is.

Comment: @crush - Apparently, once investigating whether it already is draggable, the OP would then want to act upon that element....

Comment: @JosephSilber So you are chastising my approach based on the author's undisclosed intent. Maybe that is why he said he didn't want your solution - because you don't know his intent either.

Comment: @JosephSilber  I don't want to depend on something that is easily editable outside of the scope of my app

Comment: @kidwin - By that same account, the `data` is also easily editable outside the scope of your app.

Comment: That is true I agree. You have a point, what is right is right.